# App Engine DataStore: How can I mass delete datastore entities on localhost?

Tags: google-app-engine

Unfortunately I had a job that populated the DataStore on my localhost with 10,000's of entities. I want to delete them. When the number of entities are small, I go to `localhost:8080` and delete them manually, but not that there are so many, deleting 20 at a time its taking *way* too long and I need something like a bulk delete. On prod I use DataStore Admin on the old console, is there something similar on localhost?

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole local datastore, or just a selection of entities?

Comment: Actually just one kind of entity, but since its so painful doing it 20 at a time, I'm ok deleting the whole datastore as well, yes that's certainly an option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the entire local datastore by starting the dev server with `--clear_datastore=yes` - see [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Using_the_Datastore).